# Springboot/Thymeleaf check current user from model on every page

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to provide the following model to every page so that I can check if the current user is logged in, and therefore control header menu items for every page, but I don't want to always return index. Is there any way to return self?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String index(Model model) {
 Users user = usersRepository.findOne(1 L);

 if (user != null) {
  String currentRole = user.getRole().toString();
  model.addAttribute("currentRole", currentRole);
  // System.out.println("Current Role: " + currentRole);
 } else {
  model.addAttribute("currentRole", "ANONYMOUS");
 }

 return "index";
}
```

My menu:

```
<li th:switch="${currentRole}">
   <!-- Is Employee, so show "My Requests" -->
   <div th:case="EMPLOYEE">
      <a href="#" th:href="@{/requests}">
         <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">My Requests</div>
         <!-- Handle notifications here -->
         <div style="overflow: hidden" id="circle">1</div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <!-- Is Manager, so show "My Approvals" -->
   <div th:case="MANAGER">
      <a href="#" th:href="@{/requests}">
         <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">My Approvals</div>
         <!-- Handle notifications here -->
         <div style="overflow: hidden" id="circle">1</div>
      </a>
   </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#" th:href="@{/team}">My Team</a></li>
<!-- Is logged in, so don't show "Log In" -->
<li th:unless="${currentRole}">
   <a href="/login" th:href="@{/login}" class="btn-login">Log In</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `Spring` you can create `@ControllerAdvice` class and place there desired logic, something like this (not tested)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class UserRoleAdvice {

    // ... autowire needed services

    @ModelAttribute("currentRole")
    public String currentRole() {
        Users user = usersRepository.findOne(1 L);
        if (user != null) {
            return user.getRole().toString();
        } else {
            return "EMPLOYEE";
        }
    }
}
```

This will add this parameter for all pages...

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter where I place this class relative to root?

Comment: You just need to place this class in directory which is under auto-scan, or simply together with controllers

Comment: Cool. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get the parameter on some pages but not others. It seems to only work on pages that are already getting the User object. Not sure why.

Comment: What do you mean? That this parameter `null` on some pages?

Comment: Yes it's null on some pages. Seems to be the pages that the UsersRepository is not available at.

Comment: That's very strange, because ControllerAdvice should add this attribute to all models. That means that or you have some kind of weird misconfiguration, or mistake on that pages. It would be interesting to see parts of these code (controller + page source block) where this doesn't work. If you can add it to your question, may be I would be able to help you further.

Comment: The three pages where this does not work is the root localhost:8080/, and two pages that do have a request mapping, /team and /home.

Comment: It worked as soon as I added a request mapping in my IndexController for the three pages that were missing one.

Comment: Nice :) I'm glad that you've found the problem

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring security, Thymeleaf has an integration module that deals with this directly in you templates, so you probably don't even need the username in the model. Add a dependency to the appropriate version of `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4`.

Then add the xmlns to you html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
            xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

and you can do

```
<div th:text="${#authentication.name}">
    The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
</div>
```

More info about the [Spring Security Integration module](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity)